# hyperlink line still showing even with 'text-decoration:none;'

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am trying to take the line away from the hyperlink in my footer and header. Heres the css code:

```
    ul.footer li{
         color:#000000;
         list-style-type: none;
         display: inline;
         text-decoration: none;
         padding:10px 70px;
         background-color: #009999;

        }
   ul.nav li{
        list-style-type: none;
        clear:both;
        height:100px;
        display:inline;
        background-color:#009999;
        padding: 10px 60px;  
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

also heres my website:
reachout2parents.com

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you cannot remove the line of a link by changing the li text decoration property, only by changing the a styles this will work so try adding ul.nav > li > a { text-decoration:none }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to apply the style directly to the `a` element in your `li`.

```
   ul.nav li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

the hyperlink is identified by the `a` element, try this instead:

```
ul.footer li{
         color:#000000;
         list-style-type: none;
         display: inline;
         padding:10px 70px;
         background-color: #009999;
        }

   ul.nav li{
        list-style-type: none;
        clear:both;
        height:100px;
        display:inline;
        background-color:#009999;
        padding: 10px 60px;  
        }

   ul.footer li a{
         text-decoration: none;
        }

   ul.nav li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style seems applies to the `li` elements instead of `href` elements?

Answer (score 0):

The `text-decoration: none;` should be on the `a` tag, not the `li`, try this:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This will affect all hyperlinks, not just the header and footer.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
 a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: This line on it's own will remove all text decoration from all hyperlinks on a page that uses this CSS. The OP only wants to remove it from the header and footer.